# Get date of last occurrence of a specific weekday dynamically

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to create a function that returns the date of a specific weekday, the last time it occurred.

For example, today it's Tuesday, 2016-08-16. If I was looking for last Friday, it should return 2016-08-12.

Currently, the code I'm using is written for a specific weekday. How could I change this to make it return the date of whatever weekday I'm asking for?

```
let t = new Date().getDate() + (6 - new Date().getDay() - 1) - 7;
let d = new Date();
d.setDate(t);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var WEEK_DAYS = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 86400000;

function lastOccurrenceOf(weekDay) {
  var desiredIndex = WEEK_DAYS.indexOf(weekDay);
  var currentDate = new Date;
  var daysDifference = (currentDate.getDay() - desiredIndex + 6) % 7 + 1; //the number of days ago
  return new Date(currentDate.getTime() - MILLIS_PER_DAY * daysDifference);
}
console.log(lastOccurrenceOf('Tuesday').toString());
console.log(lastOccurrenceOf('Friday').toString());
```

Comment: There's a slight bug where it will return today's date if you ask for the last occurrence of today's weekday.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function I wrote that works for all cases.

```js
/**
 * @param {Date} date - the initial Date
 * @param {('Mon'|'Tue'|'Wed'|'Thurs'|'Fri'|'Sat'|'Sun')} day - the day of week
 * @returns {Date} - the Date of last occurrence or same Date if day param is invalid
 */
function getLastDayOccurence (date, day) {
  const d = new Date(date.getTime());
  const days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
  if (days.includes(day)) {
    const modifier = (d.getDay() + days.length - days.indexOf(day)) % 7 || 7;
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - modifier);
  }
  return d;
}
```

Per your example, if today is Tuesday, 2016-08-16, the previous Friday could be found as follows:

```js
const lastFriday = getLastDayOccurence(new Date('2016-08-16'), 'Fri');
```

Also answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59144918/5436697

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's a way to do it easier, but here's my take.

```js
console.log("Monday", getLast("Monday"));
console.log("Tuesday", getLast("Tuesday"));
console.log("Friday", getLast("Friday"));

function getLast(dayName) {
  var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  var dayNum = days.indexOf(dayName);
  var todayDate = new Date();
  var todayDay = todayDate.getDay();

  if (dayNum >= todayDay) todayDay += 7;

  var diff = todayDay - dayNum;
  diff = diff * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

  return new Date(todayDate - diff);
}
```